# Why doesn't useState() allow for concatenation of Boolean values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to dynamically generate some dropdowns in react and each new dropdown will be referencing an index in an array that is held in my state, but for some reason `setState()` with boolean values won't allow for concatenation.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [dropdownName, setDropdownName] = useState(["All"]);
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState([false]);

  const addNewDropDown = () => {
    setDropdownOpen((prev) => [...prev, false]);
    setDropdownName((prev) => [...prev, "All"]);

    console.log(dropdownName);
    console.log(dropdownOpen);
  };

  const toggleDropdown = (index) => {
    var newMap = dropdownOpen.map((e, i) => {
      if (i === index) return !dropdownOpen[i];
      else return dropdownOpen[i];
    });
    setDropdownOpen(newMap);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
        onClick={() => {
          addNewDropDown();
          toggleDropdown(0);
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

/* How it looks in my acutal code for refenrece.

<Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen[index]} toggle={() => { toggleDropdown(index) }}>
  <DropdownToggle caret>{dropdownName[index]}</DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownItem>All</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem divider />
      {
        dropdownFilters[index].map(item => {
          return (
            <DropdownItem>
             <div onClick={() => {
              setDropdownName(item.Name);
              getProductTypeFilters(item._id);
              addNewDropDown()
              }}>{item.Name}</div>
              </DropdownItem>)
           })
      }
  </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>)

*/

export default App;
```

Old State

```
["All"]
[false]
```

New State

```
["All", "All"]
[false]
```

Desired State

```
["All", "All"]
[false, false]
```

I've tried creating a new variable which is the old array and concatenating it with the new value, I've tried substituting `prev => [prev, false]` with `prev => [...prev, false]`, and I even tried doing `setDropdownOpen([false, false]), but for some reason that state seems immutable. Can booleans not be appended to with useState()?

Here is a link to the issue being replicated in coderpad[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/event-handling-in-react-forked-tqc2y?file=/src/components/App.jsx)

Comment: The output doesn't match the code. You'd get `[[false], false]` based on what I see here... `[...prev, false]` looks correct. Seems like something else is amiss. Where are you accessing these values? `console.log` somewhere, debugger or rendered? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ggorlen is right... something fishy here. But if you want to concat, simply do `setDropdownOpen(prev => [...prev, false])` so that you're not nesting arrays inside of arrays.

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct. I duplicated the above code (with recommended suggestions) in code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/event-handling-in-react-forked-tqc2y?file=/src/components/App.jsx and it appears to be functioning the way I'd expect. I presume there is something awryelsewhere in my code.

Comment: @ggorlen @mpen I figured out what is causing the issue, but I am not sure why. So I am using these for the dropdown toggle state. `false` means closed. I have a function called `toggleDropdown()` which opens and closes the dropdown by switching the given state if it is the same id as. Can either of you tell why this isn't allowing for the state to be added to? If you click the link in my earlier comment I have updated the code

Comment: I'd update the code _in the post itself_ so others can benefit from a reproducible example. The idea is to show a clear problem and have a clear answer for threads to be helpful on this site. Links and external sites go down over time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `onClick` handler ends up enqueueing multiple state updates.

```
onClick={() => {
  addNewDropDown();
  toggleDropdown(0);
}}
```

The state update from `addNewDropDown` that updates `dropdownOpen` is overwritten with the state update from `toggleDropdown`. `setDropdownOpen(newMap);` in `toggleDropdown` isn't using a functional state update so it is incorrectly updating from the state from the last render cycle versus updating from the last state update.

```
const toggleDropdown = (index) => {
  var newMap = dropdownOpen.map((e, i) => { // <-- dropdownOpen is unupdated state, i.e. [false]
    if (i === index) return !dropdownOpen[i];
    else return dropdownOpen[i];
  });
  setDropdownOpen(newMap); // <-- non-functional state update
};
```

## Solution

Use a functional state update in `toggleDropdown`. Map the previous state to the new state and toggle the value that matches the index.

```
const toggleDropdown = (index) => {
  setDropdownOpen(prev => prev.map((el, i) => i === index ? !el : el));
};
```

I assume once you've gotten this function working as you expect it to you will *actually* start rendering the dropdown you mention and pass a *real* index to your `toggleDropdown` function so you aren't always toggling the first index.